# find the clockwise or anticlockwise ordering of vertices of polygon given the edge coordinates of each edge

Tags: 2d, polygon

Given edges of a polygon (ex: edge  1 (x1,y1), (x2,y2)) find the clockwise or anticlockwise ordering of vertices of polygon

Answer (score 0):

Find the center of the polygon, by calculating the average coordinates over all points => `(xc, yc)`. Then sort the points according to their angle of rotation about this point.

The comparison operation for sorting can be the *2D cross-product*: `(a, b) ^ (c, d) = a * d - b * c` for two vectors; if this is positive then `(c, d)` is rotated *clockwise* with respect to `(a, b)`, and vice versa.

In the code then the operation to compare two points is `(x1 - xc, y1 - yc) ^ (x2 - xc, y2 - yc) > 0`. If this is true then `(x2, y2)` lies to the "right" of `(x1, y1)`, and vice versa.

Comment: Would this method work for convex or concave hulls? Or would it work for both? I am wondering, what would happen if the center is outside of the polygon?

Comment: @philm there are some cases where an outright CW/CCW ordering cannot be established, e.g. when the center is outside the polygon, or when from the POV of the point some vertices "fold back"